# Apache Kafka vs Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

When I create a Spring Project on the selected dependencies screen under the Messaging section I see **Spring for Apache Kafka** and **Spring for Apache Kafka Streams**. What is the difference between these two?

[image]

Comment: 1. is [Spring for Apache Kafka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka)
2. is [Spring Cloud Stream](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream) with [Kafka Binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka)

Comment: This article has some info on this: https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-2-apache-kafka-spring-cloud-stream.  In the section called "Creating a Kafka application by using Spring Cloud Stream" it creates an example app using the first reference (Spring for Apache Kafka).  In the "Overview of Kafka Streams support in Spring Cloud Stream" section it instead creates an example using the second reference (Spring for Apache Kafka Streams).  And in that section it explains some of the features of the binder in this dependency.